# Can we mutualize the streaming KPIs in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In 'tf.metrics', [multiple streaming metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics) are defined which retun both a Tensor and an `update_op`. Some of them, `tf.metrics.auc` for example, compute internally local variables (`true_positives`, `true_negatives`, `false_positives` and `false_negatives` in the case of `auc`), [see here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc).

Let's say I want to monitor `auc` as well as all the four true/false-negatives/positives metrics. I can create five `update_op` using `tf.metrics.auc`, `tf.metrics.true_positive`, etc.

However, in this case, each true/false-negatives/positives will be computed twice... **Is there a way to get the local variables computed in `auc` in order to avoid to recompute multiple times the same metrics and thus to save computation time?**